# Mocking a Static Class

Tags: .net, mocking, static-classes

I have a static class that wraps some native methods from winspool:

```
public static class WinSpool
{
     [DllImport("winspool.drv")]
     public static extern int OpenPrinter(string pPrinterName, out IntPtr phPrinter, IntPtr pDefault);
     ...
     //some more methods here
}
```

I would like to mock them for unit testing, but couldn't find a pattern for this. (Does everyone avoid static classes?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, static class is generally [frowned upon in the field of unit testing and mocking](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2009/11/12/test-driven-design-willed-vs-forced-designs.aspx). AFAIK no open source mocking framework ( such as [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)) support static class mocking

If you absolutely and positively must mock static class, then I afraid that you must go for [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com), which is not free.

Comment: I find it ironic how static members are "frowned upon", when what we really should frown upon are mocking frameworks that cannot mock static members. After all, if TypeMock can do this, why can't OSS frameworks do the same?

Comment: The reason for this is that most mocking frameworks implement mocks using the Proxy pattern, which essentially requires inheritance, and of course static classes cannot be inherited from.  Typemock uses an entirely different approach, by redirecting method calls with IL injection, which gives it the power to mock static calls.

Comment: Because it is *too expensive to be developed for free* (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534119/is-there-any-open-source-mocking-framework-resembling-typemock)

Comment: I think a tool that would help mocking static classes is a extract interface and wrap implementation tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035188/net-tools-extract-interface-and-implement-wrapper-class

Comment: "Here is the deal. I don't like the idea of mocking statics.
Given a patch that would add this capability to Rhino Mocks *, I would apply it in a heartbeat." -> http://ayende.com/blog/3325/would-i-add-static-mocking-to-rhino-mocks

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has produced a Fakes framework for Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate that allows static types to be mocked using shims. Shims are "fake" assemblies that provide delegates for all externally accessible methods. Calls are then routed through the event filter, and wherever the test has set up one of its delegate, the delegate handles the call. Not that anyone wants to encourage static types that aren't handled through dependency injection. The prefered direction is to move away for the need for shims and toward the use of stubs using DI.