# C#: P/Invoke and Unit Testing

Tags: .net-core

I have been following the guidelines from:

- https://www.meziantou.net/stop-using-intptr-for-dealing-with-system-handles.htm

So basically I have now a wrapper class on top of my native code as follow:

```
public sealed class MyFileWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MySafeHandle _handle;
    // implement cstor and Dispose() as recommended

    public int ReadFile(byte[] bytes, int numBytesToRead) {
      int ret = NativeMethods.ReadFile(_handle...);
      // ...
      return numBytesRead;
    }
}
```

with:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
[...]
    // Take a SafeHandle in parameter instead of IntPtr
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    internal extern static int ReadFile(MySafeHandle handle, byte[] bytes, int numBytesToRead, out int numBytesRead, IntPtr overlapped_MustBeZero);
[...]
}
```

What would be a good practice to unit test this `ReadFile` function (using Xunit) ? It seems like the static class `NativeMethods` is [against good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823750/136285) for unit testing, so I was wondering what people do in this case. It seems that hiding the implementation detail of `MySafeHandle` is part of the solution, so I suspect turning `NativeMethods` into an interface would expose too much of the low level.

Comment: do you want test the method itself(i think by dllimporting you've assume it is tested), or other business logic that uses this method(use interfaces)?

Comment: I am planning on doing both, goal is to have 90% coverage.

Comment: i think reading a file is not hard to unit test, since you can embed some small test files in project and i think the test won't take too much time. however, in general there are other native methods that could be much harder to test.

Comment: Just don't write that code and you won't have to test it.  You only have to pinvoke CreateFile().  Use the FileStream(SafeFileHandle, FileAccess) constructor to wrap it.  Now FileStream.Read() will call ReadFile() for you.